# Adding a drop down menu in the force-layout (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, drop-down-menu, force-layout

Based on this example: http://bl.ocks.org/jfreels/6734245

When i use a code that contains this single line in D3.js, :

```
<script>
var select = d3.select('body').append('select')
</script>
```

Then an empty drop down menu on the upper left side of the screen appears.
So my plan was to copy and paste the drop down menu in a force-direct layout based on this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

But unfortunaly it did not worked. Is it because i use `d3.select('body')` to create the drop down menu?

Comment: Could you include what didn't work?

Comment: Yeah, the drop down menu did not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It works perfectly fine when you add the `<body>` tag.

Your code would look something like (excluding scripts, and style):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</body>
```

Make sure have the `script.js` file in the right directory. Else copy the code into a `<script> </script>`tag. I cannot recommend this though.

Comment: Thanks, what is this `src='script.js'` for?

Comment: Not sure if i make it right, but i think your tip don't work.

Comment: In blocks the users script is called script.js.
Store the script in a file as script.js and you'll get your result.
Or as i write put it into a script tag.

It seems like you have some VERY fundamental questions here. you should probably take an introductory tutorial in javascript or d3 javascript.

Take a look at this d3 one - it's currently free: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345